# Dynamic DataTable Creation in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, datatable

I have membership database which contains Roles defined in the role table..Now i want to make datatable to be created dynamically from the the number of roles present in roles table...

here is my code..

```
DataTable dTable = new DataTable();

string[] rolesarr = Roles.GetAllRoles();
int length = rolesarr.Count();

for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
{
     string colname = rolesarr[i];
     if (i == 0)
     {
         dTable.Columns.Add(colname, typeof(string));
     }
     else
     {
         dTable.Columns.Add(colname, typeof(bool));
     }
}
```

but it is giving error as

> *"System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array."*

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your

```
i <= length
```

to

```
i < length
```

Because arrays are zero based. Their bounds are `0` to `length - 1`.

From [`Arrays (C# Programming Guide)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9b9dty7d.aspx)

> Arrays are zero indexed: an array with **n** elements is indexed from **0** to
>   **n-1**.

For example, when you declare an array with 5 elements like;

```
int[] array = new int[5];
```

Your elements as indexed from `0` to `4` like;

```
array[0]
array[1]
array[2]
array[3]
array[4]
```